# Gephi export to PDF does not export node labels

Tags: pdf, export, label, gephi

I am trying to pull a PDF of a network. The node labels are currently on my graph when in Gephi, however, when I export it the node labels disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Preview Settings make sure you have the Show Labels icon selected and then refresh before exporting.

[image]